# Wrap array around sphere

Tags: modifiers, shrinkwrap, curve-modifier

I want to wrap an array of cubes around a sphere (which is not perfectly round). What's the best way to do that? I tried to use a Curve Modifier but working with two curves (for X and Y axis) doesn't really work here. Also the shrinkwrap modifier wraps my objects around the sphere but only where they touch it. You can see my problem in the picture below.

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: If you want an object aligned on each face normal, investigate 'Instance on Faces'. For instance, watch [this video tutorial](https://youtu.be/a77tS9bukvU).

Comment: Do you want the cube to deform or do you want to avoid that? It should be possible with 2 Curve modifiers but you could also use a Simple Deform modifier in Bend mode on Z for example

Answer (score 3):

There are several solutions, you could use a *Curve* modifier to make it bend on Z:

[image]

Then a *Simpled Deform* modifier, *Bend* mode, 120° (or whatever) on Z, with an empty as *Origin*, and move the empty until the cubes sticks correctly:

[image]